# Storing Kerberos authentication for later impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

Is it possible to store a Kerberos ticket to later use it to impersonate the user?

I have the scenario where a user directly invokes an external system to process some data. The external system relies on the user being impersonated/authenticated correctly in the AD.

Now the calling system has to change so that a queue sits between the user and the external system and work from the queue is handed over to the external system from that queue by a Windows service.
This service needs to impersonate the user in order for the external system to correctly handle user-rights.

Given that I can't change the external system and can not store the username and password in the queue, can I save a Kerberos ticket when the user adds new work items to the queue and later impersonate the user by the service when it hands over the data to the external system. How would I do that in C#?

Comment: which kind of queue your service is using ? a systeme message queue, an MSMQ ? Because if the queue you are using is based on RPC, your service can impersonate the end user.

Answer (score 1):

- **Edit:** This is the closest I can get to your actual question: Can you start a separate thread under impersonation, make the request from there, however long it takes? Under the covers this will do what is needed (unless the service process is terminated of course).

As a microsoft guy once told us "security is the thing which stops your application working when you deploy it". (His point was to test with a realistic security setup).

The ticket may have a lifetime of 10 hours but that is the time from when it was issued. It may only have a fraction of that left by the time the user makes the request.

I suggest you simply solve the underlying problem in a different way.

What is the reason why you now need to queue? Simply because the external service is choked at peak times?

- Can you beef up or scale out the hardware? Usually the cheapest way.
- Do you actually have completely separate permissions or do the users slot into a finite number of roles? If roles you could record the role the user was in, and use specially created usernames to access the external service, one for each role.
- Is the external service yours? Can you add a "pretend to be Bob" option that doesn't rely on Windows Impersonation?
- Can you start a separate thread under impersonation, make the request from there, however long it takes? Then mail it back to the user? (yes this will under the covers be doing what you ask)
- Finally you could place the user in a browser "ration queue". I.e. issue them with a number, then have the browser refresh every 10 seconds (or use Ajax) to tell them how many people ahead of them in the queue. When it is their turn, make the actual request under impersonation. (This requires them to keep the browser window open while waiting in the queue, and also requires you to keep track of outstanding requests and active browsers vs. gone-away browsers). Nasty, but will work.

Without knowing the actual problem, it is hard to advise, other than to say don't do it this way - too many gotchas.

Comment: The queue was choose due to multiple requirements/restrictions (Service is not available 24/7 but items need to be added to the queue, the queue has to be reliable (that includes survive a reboot), the external service is choke, the client needs to add work for the external service but can log off before the work starts or finishes)
The external service is not under my control, thus no "pretend to be Bob" option can be added.
And while the ticket may have a shorter lifetime it still can be renewed above the 10 hours maximum.
TL;DR: The queue is a requirement, any solution has to survive reboot

Comment: @GaussZ: A solution which survives a reboot is an horrendous security hole. Think about it. There is a reason why this is hard to do - because it isn't a good idea. I know you said TL;DR to my other suggestions, but maybe you should take the time. Suggestions 1 or 2 are your best bets.

Comment: Of course it should not be an all-acces security hole. That is why the Kerberos token approach is favored. If someone is in a position to compromise the server and use the Kerberos tokens stored in a queue he is already in a position to compromise the web services and use tokens send to them.
I would like to use another approach as well, and am grateful for your suggestions, but since the restrictions are what they are (especially the inability to modify the external system) this idea did strike me as the best option.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to save it, but I think the ticket will be short lived. Unfortunately, you'll definitely run in to the [Kerberos double-hop issue](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx) where authentication fails from service to service unless you have delegation properly set up on your network. This will require you to set up some SPN's (service principal names) on your active directory to tell the servers to trust each other.

I've never tried to save Kerberos tickets for any length of time so even after fighting with delegation and SPNs it may not work.

Here's a quick post on setting up [IIS7 to handle double hop Kerberos tickets](http://forums.iis.net/p/1179968/1989185.aspx) and another article on [handling it from the networks point of view](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/03/07/kerberos-solution-for-double-hop-authentication.aspx).

I wish I could be of more help, and posting code and not articles - but as you investigate you'll see this is the bane of Kerberos authentication. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the double-hop issue should be taken care of. The only piece missing is getting the Kerberos ticket in code and storing it for later re-impersonation.

Comment: How long are you talking about when you want to store it? A minute, a couple hours? If I remember right, the ticket has a lifetime of 5 minutes before it expires.

Comment: The default lifetime of a Kerberos ticket should be 10 hours. It can be prolonged too by renewing it afaik. Where did you get the 5 minute limit from?

Comment: Sorry, that was the default time skew.... I think you'd be able to duplicate the token of the incoming request (you haven't said how they send the request) and store that duplicated token along with the details of the request. Then create a new WindowsIdentity based on that token to impersonate at the time of the call to the external system.

Answer (score 0):

This solution comes with a huge caveat, but instead of storing tokens/tickets, you could use the [LsaLogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and constrained delegation to obtain a token for impersonation *without* supplying credentials, at the moment the work is ready to be dequeued.

This is how protocol transition is implemented, in which non-Windows credentials (e.g. on a public website) can be mapped to a domain user who is impersonated for access to internal resources.

The caveat is, this is obviously a huge potential security hole, and the account running the process which calls `LsaLogonUser` has to be granted `SeTcbPrivilege` ("Act as part of the operating system").

If there is a way of storing a ticket, that would obviously be much better, but the first thing I thought when I saw the question was the expiry time problem that @Ben mentioned.

Edit:
[A couple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188757.aspx) of [excellent articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163500.aspx) on protocol transition and constrained delegation, with extensive coverage of the risks involved.